# Как снизить вес видео в adobe after effect?

Tags: изображения, видео, adobe, after-effects

Когда я делаю видео в Adobe after effect вес короткого видео(~30 секунд) достигает 500 мегабайт, Как снизить вес видео?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Понимаю Вашу проблему, сталкивался с этим.
Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Уменьшить качество видео (например не 3840x2160, а 1920x1080).
2. Если не можете пожертвовать качеством в разрешении, то можно уменьшить частоту кадров в секунду (например не 60fps, а 30 или вообще 24), большинству пользователей разницы будет не видно.
3. Если 1 и 2 варианты уже проделаны или условия задания не позволяют это сделать, то рекомендую воспользоваться бесплатной программой Avidemux, весит совсем мало, но Ваши запросы думаю удовлетворит. [image: Avidemux] Открываете свое видео в нём, меняете в настройках нужный вам формат (например MP4) и самое главное меняете кодек (попробуйте разные, посмотрите результат и качество видео), я бы порекомендовал Mpeg4 AVC (x264) - этот кодек поддерживается большинством видеоплееров, так что с произведением проблем не должно быть и далее "сохранить как". Можно прогнать 2-3 раза :) и что самое важно для Вас размер видео файла уменьшается значительно.

PS: Если и это Вам не поможет, пишите мне, покумекаем еще. Поподробнее опишите потом своё ТЗ(текст задание) и придумаем решение. Думаю 3 вариант это то что Вам нужно.

Comment: Как насчёт просто изменить битрейт или crf?

Comment: @andreymal эти параметры задаются перед рендерингом в after effect, а пользователя не устраивает размер размер файла на выходе, думаю он уже подвигал эти ползунки в нужное качество видео, они очень сильно влияют на качество картинки.

Comment: Скорее всего неправильно думаете, по крайней мере автор не сообщал, что он двигал или не двигал